# In an Android gradle build, how I can I make it consider a task not UP-TO-DATE when the output directory is not exactly the same?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using gradle for an Android project.

I have a task that downloads some files to put them into the build (as Android assets).

I would like to have a task download some files from the web and put them into a temp directory, from where they are copied (by a separate copy task) into the assets directory during the build.

I would like to make sure that the downloader task will rerun ( and not be considered UP-TO-DATE ) if the output directory changed in any way ( e.g. files changed or missing, directories missing, files in subdirectory missing etc, recursively. ). Currently, I specified the output directory as @OutputDirectory, but it seems to not do what I want:

```
class AssetDownloaderTask extends DefaultTask {
    @OutputDirectory
    def File outputDir

    @Input
    def String databaseChecksum
    ....
```

E.g. if I delete a file from one of the subdirectories, gradle still considers the task UP-TO-DATE. Isn't gradle supposed to store a hash of the outputs?

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Gradle expert by any means, but I believe you want to use the `@InputDirectory` annotation instead.

> This will cause the task to be considered out-of-date when the directory location or contents have changed.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/InputDirectory.html

*EDIT: Wow, didn't notice this was so old. Sorry if necroing is bad SA etiquette.*